# Calculating with inverses in $\mathbb Z_7$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate $\frac{\overline{2}}{\overline{3}}$, $\frac{\overline{1}}{\overline{9}}$, $\frac{\overline{32}}{\overline{9}}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

About first example my book says: $\overline{3}*\overline{5}=\overline{15}=\overline{1}$, then $\frac{\overline{1}}{\overline{3}}=\overline{5}$; and finally $\frac{\overline{2}}{\overline{3}}=\overline{10}=\overline{3}$. It's pretty clear, except first step? From where 5 and 3 came out?

Regards

Comment: The first step is showing that the inverse of $\bar 3$ is $\bar 5$. You know that such a thing exists and is unique, but it's nice to have it written as the class of some concrete integer.

Comment: $3$ came from the fact that you are trying to calculate $\frac{\overline{2}}{\overline{3}} = \overline{2}\times\frac{1}{\overline{3}}$, so you are looking for a solution to $\overline{3}x = \overline{1}$ (in order to know what $\frac{1}{\overline{3}}$ is). As to where $5$ came from, possibly inspection, or you can express $1=\gcd(3,7)$ as a linear combination of $3$ and $7$; this quickly gives you $1 = 3\times 5 + 7\times(-2)$, so the $x$ you want is $\overline{5}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is tiny. To find the inverse of something, try stuff until you find something that works, though there are shortcuts, barely needed. What is the inverse of 9 aka 2? Can you think of something which when multiplied by $2$ gives $1$ more than a multiple of $7$? Surely $4$ jumps to mind. (Now you know the inverse of $2$ for any $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n$ odd. Others are less simple for $n$ big.)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Arturo Magidin's comment, there is an algorithm that finds the inverse of an element $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ (which doesn't involve checking all elements), assuming such inverse exists. Indeed, the inverse of $\overline{a}$ exists if and only if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, and therefore, since $\gcd(a, n) = 1$, [Bézout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) implies that $\exists \ \alpha, \ \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha a  + \beta n = 1$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be determined with the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Now, you have: $$\alpha a = 1- \beta n \equiv 1 \ \left(\text{mod} \ n \right) \Rightarrow \overline{\alpha} = \overline{a}^{-1} \ \text{in} \ \mathbb{Z}_n $$
so the inverse of $\overline{a}$ has been determined. If you want to calculate $\frac{\overline{b}}{\overline{a}}$, simply multiply $\overline{b}$ by $\overline{\alpha}$.
 
As pointed out in the comments, if you are dealing with small $n$'s, such as $7$, checking all other elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is probably faster then determining the coefficients of the Bézout Identity; however for large $n$'s the Extended Euclidean Algorithm is more efficient then an exhaustive check: the first has time complexity $O(\log^2(n))$ while the latter $O(n)$ (see [Buchmann - an Introduction to Cryptography](http://books.google.it/books/about/Introduction_to_cryptography.html?id=JEpVP9FC4o4C&redir_esc=y)).